# Show timebased plan and the people involved at each activity

Tags: team-management, planning

Disclaimer: I am not a project manager, just a software developer, so I may need some help wording this to make it acceptable.

I was talking to a company who want me to do some consulting work, defining an architecture and also Processes for a new project.

They showed me an app with columns, each representing a month, and containing things that have to be achieved that month.

They say that they have a problem with showing who is involved in each activity and making them aware of it.

Not being a PM, all that I could think of were Gantt charts, but they don't want to use those.

This seems common enough that I will hear if there is a name for it. With a name, I can ask at [Software Recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/), where I am active for an app which they could use.

Comment: Something like [Trello](https://trello.com/) or similar applications that can manage backlogs, kanban boards, etc?

Comment: That is probably what they showed me (+1), but they seemed to find it insufficient. I think that they wanted more viability of who is involved in each activity (and also to get them to communicate with each other, but that is another matter). We wee all speaking a common second language, and they hurried past the point. They didn't ask me to do anything about it, but I thought that it would be nice to try. Alas, I can't really say more about what they want. I think that I am looking for an approach, or technique, rather than a too. But a tool would also be welcome.

Comment: I'm not clear on what you're asking for, here. Are you're asking for just the name of the **kind of software** that they're asking for? Like, 'a ticketing system' or 'project management software'?

Comment: Yes, that's it (upvote). Weeell, maybe 1, 2.  But 1 is "you guys are PMs & I am not; is there an industry standard term of which I am not aware?" and 2 recommend an app, then that's a bonus, but I can always ask on s/w recs once I have the correct term